# Format All on Save Coc-Prettier

Tags: vim, prettier

I am new to Vim and using `coc-prettier` to format my files. I can use the command `:Prettier` to format my files, but want to do it automatically for ALL file types. I found this, but I need to specify the file types:

```
"coc.preferences.formatOnSaveFiletypes": ["css", "markdown"],
```

I want it to auto format on save for all. How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Countering irony with irony: Very helpful @romainl.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently formatting on all file types on save is possible as of the commit [#1150](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/pull/1150)

Seems to work for me.

The exact implementation:

```
"coc.preferences.formatOnSaveFiletypes":  ["*"]
```

Comment: Your link is an issue, not a commit

Comment: I've edited the link to point to the issue which has the lines viewable. The previous issue was tagged by this issue. So no big diff

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 3):

Taking a look at the [schema.json](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/blob/master/data/schema.json):

```
"formatterPriority": {
      "type": "number",
      "default": 0,
      "description": "Priority of this languageserver's fomatter."
```

*also referenced in the coc-prettier GitHub - [here](https://github.com/neoclide/coc-prettier/blob/master/Readme.md#prettierformatterpriority-default-1---priority-of-fomatter):*

> **prettier.formatterPriority (default: 1) - priority of fomatter**
>
> Change it to -1 if you don't want prettier to have higher priority than
> formatter provided by other language server.

Generally speaking coc-prettier uses [prettier](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html) which on the other hand makes usage of [ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/#example-configuration). Therefore (also for future problems), I'd suggest expanding your search term to broaden up the results. Anyhow, don't forget to properly declare the priority in the configuration file - *as mentioned above in the linked documentation*.

---

A little edit regarding a discussion between me and the bounty awarder [@DanMacák](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4256274/dan-mac%C3%A1k):

> Hence I wanted to find out if something like
> `"coc.preferences.formatOnSaveFiletypes":  '*'` is possible. Which I
> checked the schema for back then and found that this option is not
> viable.

After doing some further research on the added question, I found out that it isn't possible (at least to my knowledge). [`coc.preferences.formatOnSaveFiletypes`](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/blob/479a1fcdffd906edd6ec148b07377dabcb5eaf81/data/schema.json#L1015) only takes an array as an input - see below:

```
"coc.preferences.formatOnSaveFiletypes": {
      "type": "array",
      "default": [],
      "description": "Filetypes that should run format on save.",
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      }
```

Unless there is a way to include every element into an array, via e.g. the asterisk operator, chances are slim you can parse said information into the function. Or to sum things up, the functionality is unfortunately not provided the way you intend to use it.

Comment: The link to coc-prettier github doesn't lead anywhere.

Comment: @DanMacák Will update within the next hours. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: Btw the reason I added bounty was that we have a sound config in .prettierrc and .eslintrc with rules for *.ts and *html files already, which works great for formatting in VSCode with prettier plugin, but when I switched to Vim, I suddenly had to declare file extensions for on-save prettier formatting explicitly. When I remove the extensions from `formatOnSaveFiletypes`, imperative formatting still works as expected, but not format on save. I don't think flipping prettier.formatterPriority helps - I tried. It seems to me that formatting and formatting on save are 2 separate issues here.

Comment: Hence I wanted to find out if something like `"coc.preferences.formatOnSaveFiletypes":  '*'` is possible. Which I checked the schema for back then and found that this option is not viable.

Comment: @DanMacák Fixed the link. Regarding your two last comments - thanks for the input. As you mentioned, it doesn't seem to work. I tried a few things here and there, but ended up getting stuck. [coc.preferences.formatOnSaveFiletypes](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/blob/479a1fcdffd906edd6ec148b07377dabcb5eaf81/data/schema.json#L1015) only takes an array as an input and as long as you're unable to signal, via e.g. the asterisk operator, that you want "all file formats" to format this way, chances are slim you'll get it to work.

Comment: Got you. I guess this goes towards a feature request on CoC. Could you please mention in your answer that this is currently not possible? Just to have it visible there. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @DanMacák Currenrly not possible as far as my knowledge and research is concerned. Sure thing, will edit the post tomorrow as I’m currently not on the proper device to do so.

Comment: @DanMacák Updated my reply. Let me know whether anything is unclear!

Answer (score 1):

Set `coc.preferences.formatOnSaveFiletypes`to `["*"]` to enable format on all filetypes.

Answer (score 0):

**Coc-Prettier** will follow [prettier's configurations settings](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html)

`prettier.formatterPriority` (default: 1)

make sure you add the required conditions in the prettier config.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I mentioned in the other answer from @J.M. Arnold, this question is not about formatting per se, but rather about formatting on save, which is not really influenced by `prettier.formatterPriority`.

Answer (score -1):

Vim has excellent built in formatting. So you can leverage that to do the formatting for you. Add this to your `~/.vimrc` to autoformat the file on save.

```
autocmd BufWritePost * execute "normal gg=G"
```

Add the configs you require like `tabstop` and `shiftwidth` to format as you require it.

Comment: Thanks, interesting alternative. The problem is however, that this doesn't use prettier and secondly, it does the formatting AFTER the buffer is written to disk, so the formatting changes eg. don't occur in git unless you write the buffer for second time.

Comment: You can use `autocmd BufWritePre * execute "normal gg=G"`, for formatting before inserting. But yes it doesn't use `prettier`